# Cordova InAppBrowser open FTP URL Windows Phone 8

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8, ftp, cordova-plugins

I want to open an FTP URL using the Cordova InAppBrowser on Windows Phone 8 app. I am able to open an HTTP URL like this:

```
window.open('http://www.google.com','_system')
```

But in place of this if I pass a FTP URL this does not work. How can I do that? The FTP server does not have any authentication. The file is either an image or PDF.

Answer (score 0):

You can't open FTP links in InAppBrowser.

You have to develop your own cordova FTP plugin for windows because there is only 3 plugins to enable FTP on cordova, but no one for windows :
https://cordova.apache.org/plugins/?q=ftp

Comment: Is there a place where this can be submitted as a feature request?

Comment: You can ask on their Github account : https://github.com/xfally/cordova-plugin-ftp , good luck